# JavaScriptSerializer и Дата

Tags: c#, json

Добрый день.

Что мной используется: MSSQL Server, Entity, MVC4, VS2013.
Мне надо получить Json-строку, десериализовать ее в массив объектов и обработать.

Вот JSON-строка:

```
{"Data":    [{"Id":14,"RegDate":"\/Date(1391677828183)\/","RegDateString":"06.02.2014","Name":"ЗАО 1"},  
{"Id":15,"RegDate":"\/Date(1387968996950)\/","RegDateString":"25.12.2013","Name":"ЗАО 2"},  
{"Id":17,"RegDate":"\/Date(1378843200000)\/","RegDateString":"11.09.2013","Name":"ЗАО 3"},  
{"Id":107,"RegDate":"\/Date(1384113600000)\/","RegDateString":"11.11.2013","Name":"ЗАО 4"}]}
```

Строку получаю так:

```
public ActionResult TableData(TableModel request)  
{  
    var models = _dataService.GetAllData()  
        .Select(e => new TableModel()  
        {  
            Id = e.Id,  
            Name = e.ShortName,  
            RegDate = e.RegistrationDate  
        });  
    return Json(models);  
}
```

Сама модель:

```
public class TableModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Дата")]
    public string RegDateString { get { return RegDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); } }
    [Display(Name="Наименование")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

В обработчике получаю приведенную выше json-строку и пытаюсь пребразовать ее к массиву объектов через JavaScriptSerializer:

```
var type = Type.GetType([имя модели]);
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jtype = typeof(JsonData<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var tabledata = ((JsonData)serializer.Deserialize(data, jtype)).GetData();
```

И вот здесь ловлю багу с неправильным восстановлением даты из строки:

Вот результаты:

```
{"Id":17,"RegDate":"\/Date(1378843200000)\/","RegDateString":"11.09.2013","Name":"ЗАО 3"},
```

дата восстанавливается как: 10.09.2013

```
{"Id":107,"RegDate":"\/Date(1384113600000)\/","RegDateString":"11.11.2013","Name":"ЗАО 4"}]}
```

дата восстанавливается как: 10.11.2013

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно надо извлекать даты из json-строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, ошибка была на стороне сериализации набора данных. В текстовое значение даты не записывалась информация о часовом поясе.

Заменил сериализатор на JSON.Net. Все заработало.